# My bootstrap 5 nav bar cannot be closed after being clicked in mobile view

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

My bootstrap 5 navbar can be clicked to open but cannot be closed after being clicked again in mobile view.

I am using the Bootstrap v5.0 version.

Can someone help me find out the reason behind it?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="./P_logo1.png" alt="" width="35" height="35"> Physio-pedia
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active me-5" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link me-5" href="#">Hi</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link me-5" href="#">AAAA</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link me-5" href="#">BBBB</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link me-5" href="#">CCCC</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

(MOBILE VIEW)
The navbar cannot be closed after being clicked

[image]

Comment: Why are you including `bootstrap` and `popperjs` 2 times.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the separate JS links:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

or use the last released bootstrap, the 4.6.x

Comment: Thanks, guys. I should not include both bootstrap and popperjs 2 times so the the above problem would not occur.